# unexpected VARSYM, ZIMPL program

Tags: linear-programming, lpsolve, scip

I am getting an unexpected VARSYM error for my ZIMPL program, I have no idea what the problem is, here is a portion of the code

Here are the variables

```
var FWPlus1 integer   >= 0 <= 4;
var FWPlus2 integer   >= 0 <= 4;
var FWPlus3 integer   >= 0 <= 4;
```

goes up to 28, with the upper bound at 3, 2, and 1 for some of the points

here is the equation that is getting the error

```
  subto R3: FCOMx ==
    ((FWPlus1  * (FWPlus1  * 0       + 0       ))  +(FWPlus2  * (FWPlus2  * .105   + 5.47008 ))   +
     (FWPlus3  * (FWPlus3  * .2054   + 10.70110))  +(FWPlus4  * (FWPlus4  * .29683 + 15.46443))   +
     (FWPlus6  * (FWPlus6  * .48028  + 25.02197))  +(FWPlus7  * (FWPlus7  * .50223 + 26.16553))   +
     (FWPlus8  * (FWPlus8  * .50223  + 26.16553))  +(FWPlus9  * (FWPlus9  * .48028 + 25.02197))   +
     (FWPlus10 * (FWPlus10 * .43734  + 22.78483))  +(FWPlus11 * (FWPlus11 * .37529 + 19.55188))   +
     (FWPlus12 * (FWPlus12 * .29683  + 15.46443))  +(FWPlus13 * (FWPlus13 * .20540 + 10.70110))   +
     (FWPlus14 * (FWPlus14 * .105    + 5.47008))   +(FWPlus15 * (FWPlus15 * 0      + 0))          +
     (FWPlus16 * (FWPlus16 * -.105   + -5.47008))  +(FWPlus17 * (FWPlus17 * -.2054 + -10.70110))  +
     (FWPlus18 * (FWPlus18 * -.29683 + -15.46443)) +(FWPlus19 * (FWPlus19 * -.37529 + -19.55188)) +
     (FWPlus20 * (FWPlus20 * -.43734 + -22.78483)) +(FWPlus21 * (FWPlus21 * -.48028 + -25.02197)) +
     (FWPlus22 * (FWPlus22 * -.50223 + -26.16553)) +(FWPlus23 * (FWPlus23 * -.50223 + -26.16553)) +
     (FWPlus24 * (FWPlus24 * -.48028 + -25.02197)) +(FWPlus25 * (FWPlus25 * -.37529 + -19.55188)) +
     (FWPlus26 * (FWPlus26 * -.29683 + -15.44827)) +(FWPlus27 * (FWPlus27 * -.20540 + -10.68992)) +
     (FWPlus28 * (FWPlus28 * -.10499 + -5.46437)))

      /(FWPlus1 +FWPlus2 +FWPlus3 +FWPlus4 +FWPlus6 +FWPlus7 +FWPlus8 +FWPlus9 +FWPlus10 +FWPlus11 +FWPlus12 +
        FWPlus13 +FWPlus14 +FWPlus15 +FWPlus16 +FWPlus17 +FWPlus18 +FWPlus19 +FWPlus20 +FWPlus21 +FWPlus22 +FWPlus23 +
        FWPlus24 +FWPlus25 +FWPlus26 +FWPlus27 + FWPlus28);
```

the error says it is at the end at the semicolon

Comment: If i change the "==" to any other equality, the error changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but I think I figured it out, it didn't like that I was multiplying by zero in 2 of the terms